# Angular input type text onfocus date picker > value

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I've got a dateTime that needs to edit. A dateTime picker for Angular/Ionic is non-existent, so I've split the field between a date and a time field. To be able to use a placeholder and do some localization formatting (read; date formatting) I have used the `type=text` and `onfocus="this.type='date';"` trick.

This gives me esthetically what I want until I click the object. It shows a Date picker, but with the current date, not the value I use in the placeholder. Also `value=` won't do the trick. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Maybe you should show us some relvant code.

Comment: <input class="textbox-n" type="text" value="{{data.date}}" placeholder="{{data.date}}" ng-model="data.newDate" onfocus="this.type='date';">

Comment: Could it be a date formatting issue?

Answer (score 0):

This might be overkill but ui-bootstrap has a datetime picker that is easy to use - http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker

Comment: Will look into it tomorrow and post feedback.

Comment: Did you get a chance to look through this or did you find an easier solution?

Comment: It has been kinda busy, didn't find the time to work on this project. I'll pick it up this week. If a solution here or another works I'll update :)